# Ternary operator to choose an Array index

Tags: f#

> Unexpected ']' in expression

I have successfully managed to get the first part of the code working and now want to find the players real score using the index stored inside the member. I am using `playersTurn` and checking if its odd or even to represent the players turn.

The issue I am having now is using a ternary operator to get the score in the following line of code:

```
let score = this.scoring[this.playersTurn % 2 = 0 ? this.playerOneScore : this.playerTwoScore]
```

Any help would be brilliant, here is the full code:

```
open System

type Game(playerOne, playerTwo) =
 member this.playersTurn = 0
 member this.playerOneName = playerOne
 member this.playerOneScore = 0
 member this.playerTwoName = playerTwo
 member this.playerTwoScore = 0
 member this.scoring = [|0; 15; 30; 40|]

 member this.takeTurn() =
  let name = this.playersTurn % 2 = 0 ? this.playerOneName : this.playerTwoName
  let score = this.scoring[this.playersTurn % 2 = 0 ? this.playerOneScore : this.playerTwoScore]
  printfn name |> "%d is now taking their turn."
  if((new System.Random()).Next(0, 15) > 8) then
   if (this.playersTurn % 2 = 0) then incr this.playerOneScore
   else incr this.playerTwoScore
   printfn name |> "%d scored a point!"
  else
   printfn name |> "%d did not score a point!"
  incr this.playersTurn

let tennis = new Game("Player1", "Player2")
tennis.takeTurn()
tennis.takeTurn()
```

Comment: Quick look. One is an array `[| |]` and one is a list `[ ]`.

Comment: So combining Justin Niessner 's answer with this comment, should it be `this.scoring[| index |]` ? @GuyCoder

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it would. I am not an F# guy, just trying to learn haha. I appreciate it. I updated the ternary with Justins answer in all use-case @GuyCoder

Comment: Based on this and the previous question of yours, I suggest you study the F# language a bit more, and go through some of the "hello world"-type tutorials before attempting something more serious.

Comment: You should keep this code around, it would be great for a teaching exercise because the problems look simple at first, but just compound as they get fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the code work, you'll need to do a few more changes. Most importantly, you are using class with members, but those are read-only getter properties in F#. You could make them mutable, but that's not idiomatic; better option is to change the function so that it returns the new game state.

If you are learning F#, then I think it's better to make more changes and avoid using classes (they are not used that frequently in F#) and also go for a solution that does not need mutation. The following is close to what you had.

I extracted the common definitions into ordinary `let` values - you can later define a record (simple data type) to keep them, but for now, this is the easiest option:

```
open System

let scoring = [|0; 15; 30; 40|]
let playerOne = "Player1"
let playerTwo = "Player2"
let rnd = new System.Random()
```

I turned your method into a function that takes number of turns and initial scores as a tuple and returns new state. The syntax `(playersTurn, (playerOneScore, playerTwoScore))` defines a tuple with number of turns and a nested tuple with the two scores (I choose this because the two scores are logically related, so it's nice to store them together):

```
let takeTurn (playersTurn, (playerOneScore, playerTwoScore)) = 
  let name = if playersTurn % 2 = 0 then playerOne else playerTwo
  let score = scoring.[if playersTurn % 2 = 0 then playerOneScore else playerTwoScore]
  printfn "%s is now taking their turn." name
  let newOneScore, newTwoScore = 
    if (rnd.Next(0, 15) > 8) then
      printfn "%s scored a point!" name
      if (playersTurn % 2 = 0) then playerOneScore + 1, playerTwoScore
      else playerOneScore, playerTwoScore + 1
    else
      printfn "%s did not score a point!" name
      playerOneScore, playerTwoScore
  playersTurn+1, (newOneScore, newTwoScore)
```

Now you can define an initial state and call `takeTurn` repeatedly to get the next state (and the next state and so on):

```
let start = 0, (0, 0)
let step1 = takeTurn start
let step2 = takeTurn step1
```

You'll obviously want to run this in a loop - which you can do in the functional way using recursion, or using a function such as `Seq.unfold`.

Comment: Thanks for posting code that reaffirms my comment about going back to the fundamentals.

Comment: Jesus, theres a lot here I need to look into! Thank-you for this!

Comment: Are you incrementing the score correctly. It looks like `+1` instead of like Tennis with `Love, 15, 30, 40`.

Comment: @KDOT I added some more comments, hopefully explaining what I changed. The core of your logic was correct - I mostly just removed the class and the mutation!

Comment: The code does the array lookup to get `score`, but this is never printed or used anywhere - so the counting is OK, but I think you'll want to print `score` somewhere :)

Comment: Well, I appreciate you not completing the game for me :) That way, I can try it myself first! The score is going to be used later, when I've learnt what this code above does :) Once the player hits 40 they win basically @TomasPetricek

Answer (score 4):

You're using the C# syntax for a ternary operator in F#. You really need:

```
this.scoring.[if this.playersTurn % 2 = 0 then this.playerOneScore else this.playerTwoScore]
```

Comment: Missing a dot after `scoring`. Indexer access is different in F#. Also, fix the first use of the ternary operator as well.